# Aggregate raster in R and get count of contributing pixels

Tags: raster, r, terra, aggregate

I have a raster with some NULL values. I need to aggregate the raster to a coarser one, and get a count of the pixels that are being aggregated (for every output pixel), excluding the NULLs. I'm trying to use 'terra' package in R. Reproducible code below does the aggregation but doesn't give count of pixels.

```
library(terra)

s1 <- rast(nrows=12, ncol=12, nlyrs=1, xmin=-0, xmax = 12, ymin = 0, ymax = 12,
          crs = "epsg:3005",res = 1, vals = c(1:10))
s1[5]<-NA

s2 <- aggregate(s1, 4, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass aggregate a function that counts the number of non-NA values.

```
library(terra)

r <- rast(nrows=100, ncol=100, vals = runif(10000)*1000)
  r[sample(1:ncell(r), 1000)] <- NA

rcts <- aggregate(r, 4, fun=function(x) {length(x[!is.na(x)])} )
  plot(rcts)
```

Comment: or:  `rcts <- aggregate( notna(r),  4,  fun=sum)`

Comment: @RobertHijmans thanks. The `notna` function is new to me.

Comment: sorry, it should be `not.na` (still new, but it exists).

Comment: Guess my question wasn't clear but what I need is a count of non-NA's for each aggregated output pixel, and not the total count of NA's. Also, when I use my code the output raster converted to dataframe is { 5.50, 5.80, 4.75, 4.75, 6.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.50, 5.75}, which is what I want, as the default function is 'mean'.

Comment: With @JeffreyEvans code, I get output {16,  15,16,16,16,16,16,16, 16 }.

Comment: @jaykay I am not clear what you are getting at here. This is returning the count of non-NA pixels being aggregated to each pixel in the new resolution. Think of the new pixels representing polygons with aggregate intersecting the previous resolution. What is being presented are counts of the number of intersecting pixels that are not NA values thus, `length(x[!is.na(x)])` where x is a vector of intersecting pixels at the original resolution. If this is not what you want modify your question with an example of expected output.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Right, I see what you mean now!  So your solution (and RobertHijman's) just gives the number of non-NA pixels being aggregated, and then I guess I just need to add another line in the code for the actual mean of raster values. Thank you!

Comment: To create a raster of the aggregated mean just use `aggregate(r,  4,  fun="mean", na.rm=TRUE)` which may even be the default for `aggregate`